# retrieve inner value of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

my array is looking like this,

```
array(90) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "2016-03-27 0:04:06"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  .
  .
  .
  [90]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "[action] => update"
  }
```

The array name is `$array`. Here i can get the value of array using `$array[1][0]` which gives me `2016-03-27 0:04:06`.

Now i'm trying to search by value using the below command

```
$arrays = array_filter($array, function($ar) {
   var_dump($ar[][0] == '2016-03-27 0:04:06');
});
```

but it gives me `bool(false)`. what i'm doing wrong

Comment: `$ar` will be an itteration (*each object*), so change it to: `var_dump($ar[0] == '2016-03-27 0:04:06');`.

Comment: @Darren thanks it did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [*I stated in the comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322462/retrieve-inner-value-of-array-in-php?noredirect=1#comment60268026_36322462), `$ar` is an iteration of each object/element in the array. Think of it like a `foreach`.

```
$array = array(
    0 => NULL,
    1 => array(0 => "2016-03-27 0:04:06"),
    2 => array(0 => "8")
);

$arrays = array_filter($array, function($ar) {
   return ($ar[0] == '2016-03-27 0:04:06') ? $ar : false;
}); 

print_r($arrays);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-03-27 0:04:06
        )

)
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#huKEjV36o)